# Would it be copyright infringement to use a 3d model of appolo ie Without appolo's logo

Tags: copyright

I have made a 3d model of APPOLO IE car. The model doesn't contain any kind of logo of appolo. I want to use the model for a animation which I would upload on YouTube. Would I violate any law related to copyright by doing this?

Comment: What is APPOLO?

Answer (score 3):

Sculptural works can be copyrighted and a [car design would qualify](https://ccbjournal.com/articles/automobile-designs-protecting-investment-legend-intellectual-property). Also the car design or aspects of it (grill for example) could be covered by a design patent. See this [Suzuki](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD273098S/en) for example. Or [this Land Rover grill](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD794517S1/en?q=(automobile)&type=DESIGN&oq=(automobile)%20%20type:DESIGN).